# New hard disks for Xserve RAID

Tags: raid, mac-osx-server, hardware-raid, xserve

We have an Xserve in our office:

- MAC OSX 10.4
- 2 X 2Ghz Dual Core Xeon
- 2GB RAM

It has 4x250GB drives in it and we need to expand. What I am wondering is:

- Are we limited to what sort of drives
  we put in the RAID? (ie do they have to be the
  same size as existing / below a certain size)?
- Where can we get these drives from?

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are expanding your existing RAID (if I read that correctly) you should use drives that are the same size. You can use drives that are bigger, however the RAID will ignore the extra space and will effectively turn the drive into a 250GB drive.

Now if you are looking to replace drives later with a larger drive for all of them, you can replace them one by one until all the drive have been replaced with larger drives and then expand the RAID to make use of the space.

You should be contacting your vendor for the drives you are going to buy.I can't remember if you need sleds for the XServe or not. Most of the time you can get drives from just about anywhere. Just make sure you aren't buying common consumer grade drives.

Answer (score 1):

Presumbly this is a 'Late 2006' XServe (given it's got 2 x 2Ghz Xeons) which only has three internal drive slots so I'm assuming you have a 'Early 2007' XServe RAID enclosure which can take up to 14 x PATA-133 disks up to 500GB each. Although I'm sure Apple would say they'll only support their own drives it appears that pretty much any PATA-133 disk would work just fine, you could actually just take out one of the existing disks and look for those if they're still available. The caddies may be hard to find but I'm sure you'll find some on ebay if you look.